# Add one day to date - avoid weekends (saturdays, sundays)

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have a code that adds +1 day to the actual date.

```
var date = '30 Apr 2010';
var actual_date = new Date(date);
var final_date = new Date(actual_date.getFullYear(), actual_date.getMonth(), actual_date.getDate()+1);
```

What i would like achieve now is to avoid weekends (saturdays and sundays) when the actual date is friday.

```
Normal midweek example: 
tuesday, 5th -> wednesday, 6th

Weekend example:
friday, 6th -> monday, 9th
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a day in a loop and check if the weekday is 0 (=Sun) or 6 (=Sat):

```
d = new Date(2014, 3, 4)   // Fri Apr 04

do {
   d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)
} while(d.getDay() == 0 || d.getDay() == 6);

console.log(d); // Mon Apr 07
```

Answer (score 2):

Test `actual_date.getDay()`, which is day of week. If it's 5 (friday) add 3 days, if it's 6 (saturday) add 2 days, add 1 day otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
var date = '30 Apr 2010';
var final_date = actual_date = new Date(date);

do {
  final_date = new Date(final_date.getFullYear(), final_date.getMonth(), final_date.getDate()+1);
  var day = final_date.getDay();
} while (day == 6 || day == 0); // (6 is saturday, 0 is sunday)
```

Output:

```
Mon May 03 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var date = '30 Apr 2010';
var actual_date = new Date(date);
var final_date = new Date(actual_date);
final_date.setDate(final_date.getDate() + 1 + (actual_date.getDay() > 4 ? 7 - actual_date.getDay() : 0));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4p7Lb/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var final_date = new Date(
    actual_date.getFullYear(), 
    actual_date.getMonth(), 
    actual_date.getDay() === 5 // Friday
      ? actual_date.getDate()+3 
      : actual_date.getDay() === 6 // Saturday 
      ? actual_date.getDate() + 2 
      : actual_date.getDate() + 1 // others
);
```

Comment: Sunday is 0, Monday is 1 ... Friday is 5, Saturday is 6.

Answer (score 0):

The following example uses [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/)

```
var aDate = moment("22. Apr. 2011");  // your starting date
var DAY_IN_MSEC = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; // a day represented in milliseconds
var fiveDays = 5 * DAY_IN_MSEC; // five days


var newDate = moment(aDate + fiveDays); // add your 5 days to original date
var dayOfWeek = newDate.weekday(); // get the index of the day  *locale dependent
if (dayOfWeek >= 5) {             // is saturday, sunday *locale dependent
   var daysToMonday = 7 - dayOfWeek;
   newDate += daysToMonday * DAY_IN_MSEC; // add the difference needded until Monday
   newDate = moment(newDate); // transform the msecs in a moment object
}

alert('voila!');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var date = '30 Apr 2010';
var actual_date = new Date(date);

// Add 3 days if friday, 2 days if saturday otherwise add 1 day.
var daysToAdd = actual_date.getDay() === 5 ? 3 : actual_date.getDay() === 6 ? 2 : 1;

var final_date = new Date(actual_date.getFullYear(), actual_date.getMonth(), actual_date.getDate() + daysToAdd);
```

Or more verbose:

```
var daysToAdd = 1;
if (actual_date.getDay() === 5)
  daysToAdd = 3;
else if (actual_date.getDate() === 6)
  daysToAdd = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `getDay()` function to check if its 5 (Friday). Then add 3 days on. See fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/JLGxQ/

```
var date = '30 Apr 2010';
var actual_date = new Date(date);

if(actual_date.getDay() == 5){
     x = 3;   
} else {
     x = 1;   
}

var final_date = new Date(actual_date.getFullYear(), actual_date.getMonth(), actual_date.getDate()+x);
```